What is the shortest path between point B on a sphere and point A away from the sphere without traveling through the sphere?
I have a point A outside of a sphere (radius r, center point S) and a point B on the surface of that sphere. How long is the shortest path from A to B, that does not travel through the inside of the sphere?
I know that path would travel through space tangentially to the sphere, hit the sphere at some point C, and then follow a great arc along the surface of the sphere (unless point B can "see" point A, at which point the problem becomes trivial). But I just cannot figure out how to find point C.
I can semi-solve the problem in 2D: The distance $\overline{AC}$ can be calculated as $\sqrt{\overline{AS}^2-r^2}$ when applying the Pythagorean theorem in triangle ASC. The angle $\phi_{CSB}$ between $\overline{CS}$ and $\overline{SB}$ is $\phi_{CSB}=\phi_{ASB}-\phi_{ASC}$, where the angle $\phi_{ASB}$ between $\overline{AS}$ and $\overline{SB}$ can be calculated from A and B, and the angle $\phi_{ASC}=\arccos{\frac{r}{\overline{AS}}}$ between $\overline{AS}$ and $\overline{SC}$ can be derived from the properties of the constructed triangle ASC. This yields the distance $\overline{CB}'=r\phi_{CSB}$ between points C and B along the circle. 
Even here, I still miss the minimization step (since there are two possible points C).
The final application for this is in programming, and it would absolutely be possible to sample the circle of possible points C and solve (parts of) the problem numerically, but it would also be equally unsatisfying :)

If $B$ is on the surface of the sphere, wouldn't $C$ be at the same location as $B$? It's the point of tangency and $B$ is where $\overline {AB}$ to go through.

$B$ could be anywhere on the surface.
The trivial part of the problem consists of all locations $B$ that are "visible" from $A$, where the shortest path is the straight line. It becomes tricky where $B$ is invisible (or on the back of the sphere when viewed from the location of $A$).

I honestly believe you need to go as far as possible using a straight line (which you can achieve using a tangent line), and continue on the circle from there.
In a drawing:

I believe the smallest distance from $C$ to $B$ is by going from $C$ to $E$ (over the tangent line), and continue of the circle up to $B$.
In order to understand why this is the smallest distance, just imagine a point $X$ somewhere on the circle between $D$ and $E$. The total distance to cross is then $|CX|$ + $\text{arclength(XB)}$, where $\text{arclength(XB)}$ is the length of the arc over the circle, going from $X$ to $B$.
It is obvious that $\text{arclength(XB)} = \text{arclength(XE)} + \text{arclength(EB)}$, meaning that you need to minimise $|CX| + \text{arclength(XE)}$. As the smallest distance between two points is a straight line, you can easily see that that minimal distance is reached when $X=E$.

If the path is restricted to a plane, then I agree with you (which OP "semi-solved"). Why must this condition be true?

I simply can't believe you can achieve the shortest route passing via three dimensions while you can do it in just two :-)

This answer would be a lot stronger (a) without all of the prevarication ("I honestly believe", "I believe"), and (b) with a proof.

I agree with your intuition.  I'm indicating that this is not a rigorous proof, and am asking you to rigorize it. $\quad$ Hint: Consider the point $E$ where we leave the sphere. How can we describe $BE$ and $EA$?

Oh right, the problem is actually not as three-dimensional as I thought it was!
To clarify, you are saying that the 2D-calculation essentially applies to the 3D case, because the path moves inside a plane?
That brings me a lot closer to the solution! Still, I am not quite there yet... How would I find out which of the infinitely many possible points E (in your drawing) would yield the shortest path?

@Tig3r: I've updated my answer, answering your last question.

Nice to know the reasoning behind that line needing to be tangential :) I did assume $CE$ as a tangent from the start, which I apparently did not communicate well. My issue was that there are multiple (circle: 2, sphere: $\infty$) points $E$ for a tangent to go through. But having thought about this again after your input and a little break, I now realize that the path can be easily split up into $CE$ = (distance to any point $E$, where $CE$ is a tangent) and $EB$ = (distance of a point on a sphere to the closest point on a great arc) which I think has been answered elsewhere on this platform.

@Tig3r: glad I could help. Please upvote or accept my answer for reference reasons (this is how this site works).

Consider $A$, $B$ on the sphere or outside, with no line of sight.

First of all, the shortest path between two points $M$, $N$ on a sphere, not going inside the sphere, is on the surface of the sphere ( this probably is true for every convex body). For consider a path
$$\gamma(t) = (r \cos u \cos v, r \cos u \sin v, r \sin u)$$
with $r = r(t)$, $u=u(t)$, $v=v(t)$. We have
$$\|\gamma'\|^2 = r'^2 + r^2( u'^2 + \cos^2 u v'^2)$$
and this decreases if we take instead $\gamma_1=\frac{\gamma}{\|\gamma\|}$.

Consider the cone with vertex $A$ tangent to the sphere along a circle $c_A$, and similar for $B$, along $c_B$.
Now consider the cones $\mathcal{C}_A$, $\mathcal{C}_B$ with vertex at the center of the sphere, with base $c_A$, $c_B$ ( they are barrier sets).
Now take a path from $A$ to $B$. It  must intersect the cone  $\mathcal{C}_A$ (say at $P$) and $\mathcal{C}_B$ (at $Q$).  The path is divided into $3$ parts.

The part from $A$ to $P$ has length $\ge$ length of tangent from $A$ to the sphere, and similarly the one from $Q$ to $B$.

The part from $P$ to $Q$ $\ge$ its projection from center on the sphere.


So we got another path formed by two tangents from $A$, $B$ to the sphere, and a path on the sphere from $c_A$ to $c_B$. But we know the the shortest path on the sphere from  $c_A$ to $c_B$.  We are done.
$\bf{Added:}$ Let's see how we calculate the shortest path between two disjoint circles on the sphere, $c_A$ and $c_B$, with centers $A'$ and $B'$.  For every point $S$ on $c_A$, and $T$ on $c_B$, we have
$$d(A',S)+d(S,T)+d(T,B') \ge d(A',B')$$
with equality when $S$, $T$ are on the segment $A'B'$ ( here distance, segment are for the spherical geometry, analogous to plane geometry).  But note that $d(A',S) = r_A$, and $d(T,B') = r_B$ are constant. So the shortest distance between circles is between the points of intersection of the center segment with the circles.

$\bf{Added:}$ A similar approach could simplify the problem if we replace the ball with a smooth convex body $\mathcal{B}$.
For the first part we need to show that we can project a path outside the body to a path of shorter length on the boundary. For this we use the map $P\mapsto \pi_{\mathcal{B}}(P)$, the closest point to $P$ in $\mathcal{B}$. Indeed, $\pi_{\mathcal{B}}$ is Lipschitz of constant $1$. For consider $P$, $Q$ outside $\mathring{\mathcal{B}}$, $P'= \pi(P)$, $Q'=\pi(Q)$. Then  the dot product  $\langle P' Q', P'P\rangle \le 0$ and similar for $Q$. We get the inequality $\|P'Q'\|\le \|P Q\|$.
Now consider $A$, $B$ not in line of sight due to $\mathcal{B}$.  Consider their tangent cones to $\mathcal{B}$ along $c_A$, $c_B$. Now from $c_A$ and $c_B$ raise perpendiculars to the boundary of $\mathbb{B}$ and get two fans that are again barrier sets for $A$, $B$.  Reduce to the problem of: minimize the sum of a tangent from $A$ to $P \in c_A$, then a path from $P$ to $Q$ on $c_B$, and a tangent from $B$ to $Q$.
$\bf{Added:}$ A Desmos 3d sketch that illustrates the use of the cones.

It seems worth saying what the shortest path between the circles is and how we know it is.

@David K: thanks for the feedback, added more details

I think that covers it very well!

Thank you for your answer! It took me a while to understand the set-up with the two cones; my point $B$ being on the sphere and the resulting cone/circle with size 0 confused me a bit. But I will keep this approach in mind in case I ever come in contact with the more general case of $B$ off the surface of the sphere :)

@Tig3r: glad that it was useful! Added a sketch in Desmos that shows the two kinds of cones.

Thanks to the feedback on this post, I was now able to solve my problem :) 
This answer is for anyone who might come across this question in the future looking for the length of the described path:
As described in the other answers, the shortest path between $A$ and $B$ would follow a tangent to the sphere until a point $T$ on the sphere, and then go along the surface of the sphere. The length of the straight path to any tangential point $T$ can be calculated using the Pythagorean theorem, and all possible points $T$ have the same distance from $A$.
The length of the shortest path between $T$ and $B$ along the surface of the sphere is only influenced by the angle $\beta$ between $\overline{ST}$ and $\overline{SB}$, and the sphere's radius $r$. Given that (as detailed in the other answers) both parts of the path need to be within the same plane, it can be said that $\beta=\phi-\alpha$, where $\phi$ is the angle between $\overline{SA}$ and $\overline{SB}$ and $\alpha$ between $\overline{SA}$ and $\overline{ST}$.
This approach also makes it easy to classify scenarios in "with and without line of sight". Points $A$ and $B$ see each other where $\phi\leq\alpha$.
The minimum path $d$ from $A$ (off the sphere) to $B$ (on the sphere) is therefore
$d= \begin{cases}
    |\vec{AB}| &  \phi \leq \alpha,\\
    \sqrt{|\vec{AS}|^2-r^2}  +  r\beta        & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$
with $\alpha = \arccos(\frac{r}{|\overline{AS}|})$ and $\phi= \arccos{\frac{\vec{SA}\cdot\vec{SB}}{|\vec{SA}||\vec{SB}|}}$.

